# Multi Level Conditional One To Many Mappings in Spring JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I need to have a mapping like below in Spring JPA

```
Teacher -> Class -> Subject
```

Teacher has Classes and Classes should be having its Subjects.

I am developing a School Management System.

I have the below tables

```
MariaDB [school-mgmt-sys]> select * from subject;
+----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
| id | code    | date_created               | last_updated               | name    |
+----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
|  1 | MATHS   | 2022-07-20 14:21:20.000000 | 2022-07-20 14:21:20.000000 | Maths   |
|  2 | SCIENCE | 2022-07-20 14:21:34.000000 | 2022-07-20 14:21:34.000000 | Science |
|  3 | HINDI   | 2022-07-20 14:21:59.000000 | 2022-07-20 14:21:59.000000 | Hindi   |
|  4 | SOCIAL  | 2022-07-20 14:22:10.000000 | 2022-07-20 14:22:10.000000 | Social  |
|  5 | ENGLISH | 2022-07-20 14:22:16.000000 | 2022-07-20 14:22:16.000000 | English |
+----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [school-mgmt-sys]> select * from class;
+----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
| id | code    | date_created               | last_updated               | name    |
+----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
|  1 | GRADE_1 | 2022-07-20 14:23:49.000000 | 2022-07-20 14:23:49.000000 | Grade 1 |
|  2 | GRADE_2 | 2022-07-20 14:23:56.000000 | 2022-07-20 14:23:56.000000 | Grade 2 |
+----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [school-mgmt-sys]> select * from teacher;
+----+----------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------------------------+------------+
| id | date_created               | email        | first_name | last_name | last_updated               | phone_no   |
+----+----------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------------------------+------------+
|  1 | 2022-07-20 14:41:18.000000 | abdm@g.com   | Abdul      | Mannan    | 2022-07-20 14:41:18.000000 | 9911223344 |
|  2 | 2022-07-20 14:41:39.000000 | anjgk@g.com  | Anji       | G Konda   | 2022-07-20 14:41:39.000000 | 9911223355 |
|  3 | 2022-07-20 14:42:04.000000 | nvdShk@g.com | Naveed     | Shaik     | 2022-07-20 14:42:04.000000 | 9911223366 |
+----+----------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------------------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to create a mapping like below

```
Teacher -> Set<Class> -> Set<Subject>
```

Teacher will be teaching multiple classes. And In each class he will be teaching different subjects.

Ex:

```
Teacher1 - Class1 -> Sub1, Sub2
         - Class2 -> Sub1, Sub4
```

So I want to have a mapping when I fetch a teacher, it has to have all classes with respective subject he teachers. Output expected is

```
teacher {
    "name" : "Abdul",
    "classes" [
        {
            "id": "Class1",
            "name": "Class 1"
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "id" : "SUB1",
                    "name" "MAths"
                },
                {
                    "id" : "SUB2",
                    "name" "HIndi"              
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "Class2",
            "name": "Class 2",
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "id" : "SUB1",
                    "name" "MAths"
                },
                {
                    "id" : "SUB4",
                    "name" "English"                
                }
            ]           
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class SMSTeacher {

    ...
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
    private Set<SMSClass> classes;
    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "class")
public class SMSClass {

    ...
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "smsClass")
    private Set<SMSSubject> subjects;

    @ManyToOne
    private SMSTeacher teacher;
    
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "subject")
public class SMSSubject {

    ...
    
    @ManyToOne
    private SMSClass smsClass;
}
```

It has created below table structure and I inserted data

```
MariaDB [school-mgmt-sys]> select * from teacher;
+----+----------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------------------------+------------+
| id | date_created               | email        | first_name | last_name | last_updated               | phone_no   |
+----+----------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------------------------+------------+
|  1 | 2022-07-20 17:40:57.000000 | nvdshk@g.com | Navid      | Shaik     | 2022-07-20 17:40:57.000000 | 9911223366 |
|  2 | 2022-07-20 17:41:21.000000 | abdMn@g.com  | Abdul      | Mannna    | 2022-07-20 17:41:21.000000 | 9911223355 |
|  4 | 2022-07-20 17:41:50.000000 | anjgkn@g.com | Anji       | GK        | 2022-07-20 17:41:50.000000 | 9911223377 |
+----+----------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+----------------------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [school-mgmt-sys]> select * from class;
+----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
| id | code    | date_created               | last_updated               | name    | teacher_id |
+----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
|  1 | GRADE_1 | 2022-07-20 17:42:46.000000 | 2022-07-20 17:42:46.000000 | Grade 1 |          1 |
|  2 | GRADE_1 | 2022-07-20 17:43:28.000000 | 2022-07-20 17:43:28.000000 | Grade 1 |          2 |
|  3 | GRADE_2 | 2022-07-20 17:44:20.000000 | 2022-07-20 17:44:20.000000 | Grade 2 |          2 |
|  4 | GRADE_2 | 2022-07-20 17:49:21.000000 | 2022-07-20 17:49:21.000000 | Grade 2 |          2 |
+----+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [school-mgmt-sys]> select * from subject;
+----+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------+
| id | code | date_created               | last_updated               | name    | sms_class_id |
+----+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------+
|  1 | ENG  | 2022-07-20 17:46:32.000000 | 2022-07-20 17:46:32.000000 | English |            3 |
|  2 | HIN  | 2022-07-20 17:46:40.000000 | 2022-07-20 17:46:40.000000 | Hindi   |            4 |
|  3 | MATH | 2022-07-20 17:46:52.000000 | 2022-07-20 17:46:52.000000 | Maths   |            2 |
|  4 | MATH | 2022-07-20 17:46:59.000000 | 2022-07-20 17:46:59.000000 | Maths   |            1 |
+----+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

to fetch the above data, am using Spring Data Rest API when I fetch teacher it will have a link to navigate to class and from there i can go to subject.

But not able to do what am looking for.
Please help.

Comment: Are you  asking us to design the model for you? You should at least try to create some entiies and then ask questions if something doesn't work. The Hibernate ORM documentation has many [examples of one-to-many associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations)

Comment: Sorry for missing the entities i had created. Added the solution i tried.

Comment: But what's wrong with that? What doesn't work?

Comment: Also, EAGER on a many-to-many doesn't sounds llke a good idea.

Comment: And in the above model lot of duplicate data in class and subject tables. We have to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of solutions. Finally I found the below solution.

I have created one to many mappings between the entities with join tables, to maintain unique data in tables.

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class SMSTeacher {

    ...
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "teacher_class", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "class_id"))
    private Set<SMSClass> classes = new HashSet<>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "class")
public class SMSClass {

    ...
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "class_subject", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "class_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id"))
    private Set<SMSSubject> subjects = new HashSet<>();;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "subject")
public class SMSSubject {

    ...
    //No mapping here, Configured only uni directional mapping.
}
```

A third table to maintain teacher-> class -> subject relation ship data.

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+
| id | class_id | subject_id | teacher_id |
+----+----------+------------+------------+
|  1 |        1 |          3 |          1 |
|  2 |        1 |          5 |          1 |
|  3 |        2 |          2 |          1 |
|  4 |        2 |          4 |          1 |
|  5 |        1 |          3 |          2 |
|  6 |        2 |          3 |          3 |
+----+----------+------------+------------+
```

Created a JPA native SQL to fetch the result as required.

```
public interface TeacherClassSubjectRepo extends JpaRepository<TeacherClassSubject, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select t.id T_ID, t.first_name fName, t.last_name lName, t.phone_no phone, t.email email, c.id C_ID, c.name C_NAME, c.code C_CODE, s.id S_ID, s.name S_NAME, s.code S_CODE from teacher t, class c,subject s, teacher_class_subject tcs where tcs.teacher_id=t.id and tcs.class_id = c.id and tcs.subject_id = s.id and t.id=?1 order by t.id, c.id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Tuple> findAllByTeacherId(Long teacherId);
    
    
}
```

Here is my service Impl method to generate the output as required.

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Object> getTeacher(Long teacherId) {

    List<Tuple> teacherClassSubjects = teacherClassSubjectRepo
            .findAllByTeacherId(teacherId);

    if (teacherClassSubjects.size() == 0)
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    SMSTeacherDTO smsTeacherDTO = null;

    String fName = "", lName = "", email = "", currCName = "", currCCode = "";
    BigInteger phone = null;
    Set<SMSSubjectDTO> subjectDTOs = new HashSet<>();
    Set<SMSClassDTO> classDTOs = new HashSet<>();

    for (Tuple tuple : teacherClassSubjects) {
        
        ...
        //Logic to fetch SMSTeacherDTO fields and Logic to construct classDTOs

    }

    smsTeacherDTO = new SMSTeacherDTO(fName, lName, email, phone, classDTOs);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(smsTeacherDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "firstName": "Anji",
    "lastName": "GK",
    "email": "anjgkn@g.com",
    "phoneNo": 9911223311,
    "classes": [
        {
            "name": "Grade 2",
            "code": "GRADE_2",
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "name": "Science",
                    "code": "SCIENCE"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Social",
                    "code": "SOCIAL"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Grade 1",
            "code": "GRADE_1",
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "name": "Hindi",
                    "code": "HINDI"
                },
                {
                    "name": "English",
                    "code": "ENGLISH"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please comment if this solution is good or if there is any better solution available for this problem.

Thanks.